# How can i merge liferay's private messanging portlet with chat portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i want to merge chat portlet with private messaging portlet. The message should be mutual in chat and in private messaging portlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source for both portlets. They do have a distinct backend, the chat polling data from its service, while the private messaging portlet fetches other data. You "only" have to write a custom portlet accessing both backend services and present them as a single stream.

How to do that, and what exactly you'd have to do is far beyond the scope of a single answer on stackoverflow IMHO